# AngularJS - Show DOM elements depending on the value of variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following AngularJS structure

```
<li ng-repeat="content in contents">
  <img src="{{content.image_url}}" />
  <div class="title">{{content_title}}</div>
</li>
```

But if "content.image_url" is NULL or it doesn't exist, I don't want to display the IMG tag. So something like

```
{{#if content.image_url}}
  <img.....
{{/if}}
```

Which is the handlebarjs way of doing a conditional check. How could I achieve this in AngularJS? Do I need a directive to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-show:

```
<li ng-repeat="content in contents">
  <img ng-show="content.image_url != ''" src="{{content.image_url}}" />
  <div class="title">{{content_title}}</div>
</li>
```

Also, I would use [ng-src](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) instead of src to avoid errors in the console while the image is loading:

```
<li ng-repeat="content in contents">
  <img ng-show="content.image_url != ''" ng-src="{{content.image_url}}" />
  <div class="title">{{content_title}}</div>
</li>
```